# How to create localhost SMTP for testing mails in PHP

Tags: php, smtp

Ok, guys i have been digging around to what is the simplest way to create SMTP for mailing testing for my project mailing functionality?

Comment: You found the answer to your own question 24 seconds after posting? What is happening here? -.-

Comment: @thatidiotguy - one of the options when adding a question is to answer it yourself.

Comment: @thatidiotguy i found my answer and then i post the question + the answer

Answer (score 0):

By getting the idea from [this](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/12/03/setup-a-testing-mail-server-using-php-on-mac-os-x/) site i have wrote a semi-automatic work around bash file you can find in my [github](https://github.com/dariushha/php-test-smtp).

In this solution you only need to [download](https://github.com/dariushha/php-test-smtp/raw/master/bootstrap) the `bootstrap` file and save it in any desired location and by executing the `bootstrap` file, you can easily setup a SMTP good for PHP development and mail debugging stuffs.

After running `bootstrap` you only need to add:
`sendmail_path = /home/<your_username>/.smtp_handler/smtp_handler.php`
in you `php.ini` file, that's all! you now have a SMTP receiver for your localhost!

Comment: @Glavić i found this http://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/ but i never used it!